# Don't understand this FileNotFoundError when trying to use pillow/PIL library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In the following code I am trying to use pythons pillow/PIL library. This is the first time using this and I am just trying to open my image to make sure it is working. I have my code I used below. I just googled an image and saved it using the name smallhouse.jpg. However I am running into the following errors below.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('smallhouse.jpg')
img.show()
```

This is the error I am getting. Do I need to download a PIL package? I am using Jupiter notebook.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e26e3b39215f> in <module>()
  1 import numpy as np
  2 from PIL import Image
----> 3 img = Image.open('smallhouse.jpg')
  4 img.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
2546
2547     if filename:
-> 2548         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
2549         exclusive_fp = True
2550

 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'smallhouse.jpg'
```

Comment: as the failure says... the smallhouse.jpg does not exist in the path, you are calling your script from.

Comment: but I have saved the image?

Comment: Is the image in the same directory as the python file?

Comment: but did you save it in your current working directory where you execute your python script from?

Comment: no that was my problem! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described here:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'smallhouse.jpg'`

Please make sure you put the image file `smallhouse.jpg` in the same directory with your notebook.

Comment: @user104 You should try to search carefully with the error name, in this case, it's is `FileNotFoundError` before open a question. Btw, if this answer help solve your problem, don't forget to give this answer a upvote and a green tick. Thank ;)